# Can I change which index a primary key uses?

Tags: primary-key, azure-sql-database, clustered-index

I have a table with a non-clustered index on the id, and a clustered index on some other fields. The fields of the clustered index are non-sequential, and are frequently modified. I'd like to change the table to use the auto-increment id column for the clustered index.

- I can't explicitly drop and recreate the index on the id, as it is used to enforce the PK.
- I can't drop the PK, because it is referenced by foreign keys.
- I would like to avoid dropping the foreign keys, because re-adding them will result in a constraint check on the existing rows, and there are a *lot* of rows.

I thought the following steps might work:

- Drop the existing clustered index
- Create a clustered index on the id
- Somehow tell the table to use *that* index for enforcing the PK constraint
- Remove the old non-clustered index
- Rename the clustered index to match the convention

Is this possible? And if so, is it a good idea?

Answer (score 3):

There are some limitations/restrictions when modifying existing Primary Keys (PK), Clustered Indexes (CI) and Foreign Keys (FK).

### General Information

When a PK is created and no CI exists, the PK will create a CI if no other index is referenced in the constraint definition.

> The Database Engine automatically creates a unique index to enforce the uniqueness requirement of the PRIMARY KEY constraint. If a clustered index does not already exist on the table or a nonclustered index is not explicitly specified, **a unique, clustered index is created to enforce the PRIMARY KEY constraint.**

***Reference:*** [Creating and Modifying PRIMARY KEY Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181043(v=sql.105).aspx) (Technet)

You can't drop/modify an existing PK if it is being referenced by a FK.

> A PRIMARY KEY constraint cannot be deleted if the following exist:
>
> - If it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint in another table; **the FOREIGN KEY constraint must be deleted first.**
> - The table has a PRIMARY XML index applied on it.

***Reference:*** [Creating and Modifying PRIMARY KEY Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181043(v=sql.105).aspx) (Technet)

### Solution

You will have to drop the existing constraints (FK and PK) and/or indexes to create the solution you are aiming for.

This can be observed by reading the following articles:

- [How to convert clustered primary key to non-clustered without dropping referring foreign keys in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2293073/1820861) (Stackoverflow)
- [How to change the primary key to be non-clustered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2604452/1820861) (Stackoverflow)
- [Modify Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/modify-primary-keys) (Microsoft Docs)
- [Creating and Modifying PRIMARY KEY Constraints](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181043(v=sql.105).aspx) (Technet)